# Is there any frameworks oriented games that run under Xamarin

Tags: android, iphone, xamarin

We are a software development company which has recently discovered `Xamarin`.

We would like to know if there are frameworks oriented games that run under `Xamarin`, in order to create an application in `C#` with a single code to build them in multiplatform (`iOS`, `Android` and `Windows` `Phone`).

Waiting for a response from you.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The framework you are looking for is [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) its moto is "Write Once, Run Everywhere".

Comment: Can we write one code and compile this same code with all these frameworks (Android, IOS, windows phone)thanks

Comment: Yes it does run on all of those platforms.